# Regular expression to limit character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to regular expression to limit a string in my code.
Below are the critierias for the string.

1. Only alphanumeric characters and  . (dot) and -(hyphen) are allowed.
2. Should not start with . or - Should start with a number or letter.
3. Only one hyphen is allowed in the entire string.
4. Multiples dots are allowed. But should not allow consecutive  dots. ( eg: **d.d.d** is allowed. But **d..** is not allowed.
5. Consecutive - and. are also not allowed. (eg:**d-.** is not allowed)

   ```
   /^([a-zA-Z\d]+[\.]?[a-zA-Z\d]{0,1})[\-]?([a-zA-Z\d]+[\.][a-zA-Z\d]{0,1})+$/
   ```

I have written the above expression. But it violates the 5th point. It allows - after dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2. `^[a-zA-Z\d]` (allowed first character)
1. ...`[-.a-zA-Z\d]*$` (allowed other characters)
3. `(?!.*-.*-)`... (disallowed two hyphens)
4. `(?!.*\.\.)`... (disallowed `..`)
5. `(?!.*-\.|\.-)`... (disallowed `.-` and `-.`)

All together now (with the negative lookahead refactored together):

```
^(?!.*(?:-(?:.*-|\.)|\.[.-]))[a-zA-Z\d][-.a-zA-Z\d]*$
```

Comment: Congrats on 100k!

Comment: @Tushar: Thanks! Got swag! \o/

Comment: doesn't allow a single character as a valid string though... not sure if that's part of OP's requirements

Comment: @A.Lau: Thanks, fixed.